# MOSFET driver circuit configuration for half bridge MOSFETs for power amplifier

Tags: audio, mosfet-driver, class-d

I am making a class D audio amplifier and I am using a MOSFET driver to control two MOSFETs in a half bridge configuration as shown in the circuit below

[image: Driver side]

When I connected the circuit without the MOSFET half-bridge, I grounded `Vs` and I got a neat output according to my needs `15 V` peak at `HO & LO`, The problems started when I connected the MOSFETs, The `HO & LO` terminals started sending out the same signal but with a max voltage of `3 V` or  probably less, then the circuit drew around 1 AMP from my voltage source and burned the MOSFET driver chip, I knew for sure that it was burned because the resistance between the `VDD` terminal and the `COM` terminal was 26 Ohms instead of the high resistance a new chip had. An engineer in my uni suggested that the problem might be caused because I was providing the 15 volts to the MOSFETs from the same node that supplies the same voltage `15 V` to my entire circuit, although my circuit was drawing only 40 milliamps from the power supply before connecting the MOSFETs.

I would like to note that the chip is [FAN7390](https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/149/FAN7390-1006883.pdf). I have fried two so far. I would guess that the common power supply might be the problem?, or it might be that the switching frequency of 125kHz the problem? The `Hin and Lin` signals are PWM signals with `15 V` peak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things wrong with that design!

- Where is the decoupling? That 15V line needs a whole pile of cap on it....
- C4???! 22uF for a boost cap, just insane, get rid of it, the 220n should be fine on its own.
- R13/14 1k, try more like 100k.
- Those mosfets, 140nC maximum gate charge?! Yea they are very, very butch fets, but you really want something much smaller and with a very much lower Qg.
- Layout? It really, really matters.
- Not the cause of the blowup, but R11/12 seem very high in value, especially given the Qg of those mosfets.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the answer. I have spotted another mistake, my `Hin & Lin` signals are 15v peak which is 3 times the input voltage rating for that particular chip. If I may ask for a few clarifications please. for the first point, what line do you mean exactly, do you mean adding a shunt cap to the VDD terminal?, because I already have that but I forgot to include it in the schematic atm. for the 3rd point, I am really confused now because I saw someone suggesting a 10 Ohm to 100 Ohm resistance range, I might be mistaken though and he might've said KOhms. The MOSFETs were available at ...

Comment: ... the lab and tbh the only thing I was concerned about was the current rating, it's my first ever electronic project and my Instructor only asked us to do a simple amplification of an audio signal in base band, but I found it as an oppurtunity to use uni's resources to learn more I guess. for the 5th point, what do you mean exactly by 'layout'. as for the last point, I know that the purpose of the diode-resistor thing is to do make the gate capacitance charge discharge faster thus creating a time delay so both MOSFETs won't work together, but I really don't know what are the ranges.

Comment: Does using a voltage regulator will help me solve the power distrubution issue? for example the LM7805.

Comment: Shunt caps (plural) between +15 and Gnd, one right on the drain of Q1, one right by the gate driver. 15V for drive is fine per the datasheet as long as your logic low is low enough, see recommended operating conditions  at the bottom of page 5 and the logic input section on page 6. 10-100R might be ok for R11/12 but with those monster mosfets I would be going for very much the bottom of that range, but for R13/14 10k - 100k or so seems more appropriate. More appropriate mosfets would be maybe 25V and 10A or so, which will be almost guaranteed to have a much smaller gate charge.

Comment: Class D power stages are really NOT baseband! They are more like AM radio transmitters! A 7805 is unlikely to help much (but a handful of 220n MLCC caps and maybe 1 100uF eleco probably would). By layout I mean how physically have you built this thing? dead bug on a bit of copper clad (acting as a ground plane), with minimal lead lengths is good, while plug in breadboard is hopeless for this sort of thing for example. I would build what the instructor asked, rather then going down a rabbit hole of complicated that I would judge you do not yet have the knowledge to pull off.

Comment: lol I am using a breadboard for it, it's a bit messing but the circuit itself is smaller than older digital projects I have worked on. As for the class D amplifier, I know it's not baseband but as I said doing it will be a good experience, the problem is I don't think I would be able to catch those mistakes you've pointed out even after graduating without trying, I doubt there is a course that would tell me the specifics that you've said. I got two 180 uF ceramic capacitors I am using as a shunt between Vcc and GND, what's funny is the approach I have taken to reduce Vcc noise at the beginning

Comment: was connecting Vcc to a low pass filter, but thinking of it again, low pass filter = shunt caps but with power loss I guess, and before I forget, I am prototyping it on a breadborad, but I am planning to make a PCB for it after I am sure everything is fine. May I ask what negative effects the High Qg is producing?, is it the reason that a high current is generated which was frying my MOSFET driver? , also why was the `HO & LO` 's voltage reduced signifacantly when I connected the driver to the MOSFET gates. Also is there a specific MOSFET chip you recommend?

Comment: Also sorry for asking too many questions, but generally I don't get someone to answer me in uni since many professors there aren't experienced with circuit design I assume, so thanks for your help :D

Comment: I found [this MOSFET](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irlz44n.pdf) doesn't look as bulky and it's sold at a local online shop.

Comment: That is a logic level mosfet, Vgs(max) is rather low at 16V if you are using a 15V rail, and Qg is not all that much lower (a little under half what you had), I would probably use something like a STP16NF06L but there are many others, Qg about 10% of that monster you picked out. Breadboarding power circuits nearly never works, dead bug it on a bit of copper clad as a ground plane, much more likely to work. Forget the professors (mostly useless people for this kind of thing), it is the lab technicians you need to be seeking the advice of, they usually know the practise.

Comment: I would not worry too much about not knowing how to do this right at graduation, nearly nobody does unless they have been a hobbyist for years before going to uni. That is what the greybeard at your first job teaches you, uni is for the theory and (especially) lots of hardcore maths, actual design chops build on what you learn at university (And very seldom involve calculating ANYTHING to three sig. fig.). High Qg means lots of switching losses and slow switching (And may explain your low gate drive voltages).

Comment: Thank you very much, you are the best. So the MOSFETs themselves were what causing my driver to burn? because I am still afraid to burn another one because sourcing them would take a big load of time. As for prototyping, I would make it on a copper board as you suggested, thank you very much again for your great help.

Comment: I reiterate comments already made about layout and decoupling. The 15V logic inputs are within the device's limits so should not have fried it. One thing to watch is that you protect the driver from excursions beyond the supply rails on its outputs, even for short periods of time. See absolute maximum ratings. This can lead to totally unpredictable behaviour. A good way to protect it is to connect Schottky diodes (perhaps 1A rating) in reverse from each driver output to local supply, i.e. COM and VDD low side, VS and VB high side. Negative voltages can come from high di/dt + lead inductance

Comment: I assume you've ensured that the PWM signals do not overlap in time. If they do you get cross conduction with fast short current spikes. Perhaps find a driver that precludes cross conduction. Regarding high Qg, the significance is that the driver has to dissipate the energy stored in the MOSFET gate capacitance. In your circuit, some will go in the diode but most in the driver. Power is gate charge x freq x Vg x 2. Might be OK but check. A few ohms in series with the diode can help. On the other hand, 50 ohms in series with gate will slow the turn on time (shouldn't fry driver though).

Comment: @SteveHubbard Hello, thanks!. The thing is the power supply can only supply 1A and the driver can take around 4.5 -5 amps I think. Maybe you are right about the Power, because I have 125Khz frequency so that might’ve what fried the driver. Hmmm why would I need a couple of Ohms in series with the diode. Isn’t its purpose to kinda short the gate so it discharges as fast as possible?. My PWM signals are in-fact over lapping for like 5 - 10 ns but I thought the resistor with a parallel diode would solve this issue?. I will try to find a MOSFET with lower Qg abd place 10 Ohms instead of 50 Ohms.

Comment: If you use a small resistor in series with the diode, some of the driver dissipation is transferred to the resistor. Yes, R11, R12 could help with overlap but there might be better ways to manage this. Although your PSU is only 1A, the driver will be capable of delivering much more than this for the very short periods required, from C4 (high side) and the decoupling cap on Vdd......if it were there. Don't forget the Schottkys too.